# SiddhiQL Pattern and Window Query

Tags: sql, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am trying to write a simple siddhi query which detects a pattern
eg: "Ice" "cream" "x" "y" "apple" "water"

where events Ice & cream both should be together and apple water should be together and x y are any random values in the window.length(6)

problem is the following query is not restricting the window.length(6) how can i achieve this?

```
from every (( s1=windowedStream[s1.val=='ice']-> s2= windowedStream[s2.val=='cream'] )
            -> ( a1=windowedStream[a1.val=='apple'] -> a2 = windowedStream[a2.val =='water'] ))
select s1.meta_timestamp, s1.val
insert into filteredStream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the existent notations, Siddhi allows you to restrict a pattern based on a time window only. Please refer the following.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Pattern

As a workaround to restricting the patterns based on a length window, you may introduce a 3rd attribute called index to the "windowedStream", where index reflects the order of event arrival (i.e. index of the 1st event is 1, index of the 2nd event is 2 and so on). Then the following query would capture the patterns occurring within a length window of 6 events.

```
from every (( s1=tempStream[s1.val=='ice']-> s2= tempStream[s2.val=='cream'] )
        -> ( a1=tempStream[a1.val=='apple'] -> a2 = tempStream[a2.val =='water' and a2.index- s1.index <= 6]))
select s1.meta_timestamp, s1.val
insert into filteredStream;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks the but the problem is I want to create a  sliding window and on that sliding window i want to detect if one event follows another eg:

A(follows)B and C(follows)D
ice(follows)cream and apple(follows)water
in a window of 6 further basically window would be treated as a chunk to detect the pattern which it holds

Comment: To my understanding, you want this pattern to occur within a sliding window of length 6, right? If that is the case, the given alternative should work.

Comment: yes thank you it works ^_^, do you know any kind of dashboard in CEP where i can publish alerts whenever this kind of event occurs?

Comment: Great to hear that! Yes, WSO2 CEP does have a dashboard where you can publish alerts. Please refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Visualizing+Results+in+the+Analytics+Dashboard

Comment: yes the problem is there is no built-in graph for the just populating the table with those values which cep filters as alert, it would be awesome if you refer me to any custom dashboard tutoral, thanks in advance

Comment: You can easily achieve this requirement with WSO2 CEP. For your output stream (filteredStream), add a UI publisher as specified here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/UI+Event+Publisher. Subsequently, you can create a table gadget. Select "Real-time Data Source" as the provider. This would allow you to select "filteredStream" as the source: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Visualizing+Results+in+the+Analytics+Dashboard.